# msgsnd: invalid argument if send uninitialized structure

Tags: c, message-queue

I got `msgsnd: invalid argument`, if I send uninitialized structure.

as follows:

Success

```
struct data foo = {};
msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&foo, data_size, IPC_NOWAIT);
```

Failure

```
struct data foo;
msgsnd(msgid, (void *)&foo, data_size, IPC_NOWAIT);
```

To my knowledge, `msgsnd()` don't mind the content of the data,
I can't understand why I got the result.

Comment: "*To my knowledge, msgsnd() don't mind the content of the data,*" Comeon its within the [1st lines of the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/msgsnd.3p.html): "*The application shall ensure that the argument msgp points to a user-
       defined buffer that contains first a field of type long specifying
       the type of the message, and then a data portion that holds the data
       bytes of the message.*"

Comment: The [msgsnd man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgsnd) tells you what can cause that error: "Invalid msqid value, or **nonpositive mtype value**, or invalid msgsz value". Now you didn't set `mtype` value explicitly so...

Comment: The root cause is I define the `mtype` as `int', thanks a lot.